# How to create loop for changing Lable[ID] in asp.net using c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to create loop for changing Lable[ID].

```
Label1.Text = multiarray[rowcount - 1, 1]; 
Label2.Text = multiarray[rowcount - 1, 2]; 
Label3.Text = multiarray[rowcount - 1, 3];
```

Please give me a code to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for(int index = 1; index <= 3; index ++)
{
    Label label = (Label)this.Controls.Find("Label" + index, false)[0];
    label.Text = multiarray[rowcount - 1, index]; 
}
```

Comment: can u show me how to add for loop to your code?

Comment: I made changes in code. check now.

Comment: error in Find word. what do I do?

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
 int count=1;
 for(Control c in this.Controls)
 {
   if(c is Label)
     {
       ((Label) c).Text= multiarray[rowcount - 1, count]; 
       count++;
     }
 }
```